# Managing 4 application as a single application in android

Tags: android-activity, android, android-keystore

I have 4 application namely **'A,B,C,D'** and one controller application called **'M'** i have only one launcher that will launch the **'M'** application .In that **'M'** application i have 4 buttons for launch that **'A,B,C,D'** apps My problem is i need to Un install  all four application when the user un install the **'M'** application from the Device

**Note : Deleting that four application must not ask for the user confirmation.
I have signed that all application under a same key store.**

Comment: Can't you just put everything all together into one signle app? Any specific reasons why you want them to be individual apps?

Comment: A single login concept a user just want to login only one time then he can access all the application with same login information.

Comment: We cant do that as single app because every applicaion contains at least 3 mb of size and all my user never use all application .

Comment: I don't think you can uninstall other apps without letting the user know. This sounds like hacking to me, with some serious security concerns :)

Answer (score 1):

```
     <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.demoapp.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
     <activity
                android:name="com.example.demoapp.MainActivitya"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
                android:name="com.example.demoapp.MainActivityb"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
                android:name="com.example.demoapp.MainActivityc"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

i hope this is useful for you.

you don't put below code in other a,b,c,d activity.

```
<intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with a straightforward solution on un-rooted devices.
A proposal, you can hide “A, B, C, D" by not assigning launch to them. Only "M" can start them by intents with special private action.

Comment: yes i have done what you mentioned above  but i want to delete  all other application when my user uninstall my 'M'  Application